# Half precision floating point support on clang for x86_64

Tags: floating-point, clang, precision

I'm trying to experiment Half precision floats (_Float16) on x86_64 (why not?). clang-17 (on ubuntu-20.04) seems to compile it correctly, but the linker shows the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/accum-5a5b62.o: in function `main':
accum.c:(.text+0x81): undefined reference to `__extendhfsf2'
/usr/bin/ld: accum.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `__extendhfsf2'
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Which command-line did you use to compile your input file ?
Do you have a small input that reproduces the problem ?